# Mathematica loop code not behaving as expected

Tags: scoping, list-manipulation, procedural-programming

```
getAvgs[A_, M_] := Module[{i, j, rArr, gArr, bArr},
   rArr = {};
   gArr = {};
   bArr = {};
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[A], i += 1,
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[A[[1]]], j += 1,
      If[M[[i, j]] == 255,
        Append[rArr, A[[i, j, 1]]];
        Append[gArr, A[[i, j, 2]]];
        Append[bArr, A[[i, j, 3]]];
        ];
      ];
    ];
   Return[{rArr, gArr, bArr}];
   ];
```

This code returned an array containing three blank arrays {{},{},{}}, meaning none of the Append functions worked. 
A_ and M_ are two images, A is 24-bit 3-channel colour, while M is black and white. They have the same dimensions, the idea is to use M as a mask to find the average colour of all pixels that are shown by the mask. However, none of the Append functions worked.

Append[{}, ImageData[,Byte][[30, 30, 3]]] correctly returned the value, so the syntax should be fine. When I made the for loop increment a counter, the counter correctly returned the number of masked pixels, so the for loop is working correctly too.

From what I know, Module basically declares the variables locally, preventing variable collisions. Is this correct as well?

Comment: the direct fix is to use AppendTo, though of course you dont really want to use for loops at all.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to find the mean for each channel of an image after masking. So, your code  could be much simpler:

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
mask = DiskMatrix[#1/10, #2] & @@ ImageDimensions@image;
channels =  Pick[Flatten@#, Flatten@mask, 1] & /@ (ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[image]);
Mean /@ channels
(*
{0.846919, 0.435261, 0.408555}
*)
```

You may compare this result with the mean over the whole image

```
Mean /@ Flatten /@ ImageData /@ ColorSeparate[image]
(*
{0.53879, 0.505329, 0.443596}
*)
```

You can easily see that the result `{R,G,B}` behaves qualitatively as expected:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

`Append` doesn't change the original list, it just returns a new one with one element added.

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
Append[list, 4]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)

list

(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

If you want to change the original list, use `AppendTo`.

```
AppendTo[list, 4]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)

list

(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the old answer, in the 2 intervening years I have realised that this is a really common beginner mistake, hopefully I won't make this kind of mistake again :P

Comment: Oops, I didn't even notice the date. For some reason this post showed up at the top of my 'active' list, so I just figured it was recent.

Answer (score 0):

In case you really want a loop.. this is prefered over using AppendTo..

```
 getAvgs[A_, M_] := Module[{i, j, rArr, gArr, bArr},
    Transpose[Reap[ 
       For[i = 1, i <= Length[A], i += 1,
          For[j = 1, j <= Length[A[[1]]], j += 1,
             If[M[[i, j]] == 255,
               Sow[A[[i, j]]]
                   ;];];]][[2, 1]]]];
```

and another way more mathematica-esque..

```
getAvgs[A_, M_] := 
     Transpose[ Last /@ Select [
        Transpose[{Flatten[ M , 1] , Flatten[A, 1]}] , #[[1]] ==  255 & ]]
```

(not to disagree about using image tools, but it may be more instructive to learn the basics without that )